# A question about the number 541456

Tags: number-theory

I found that the concatenation in base 10 of $2^{541456}-1$ and $2^{541455}-1$, gives a probable prime.
I also found about number $541456$ that:

$$5\cdot(5^2+4^2+1+4^2+5^2+6^2)=(5^3+4^3+1+4^3+5^3+6^3)$$

the equation $a\cdot(2\cdot a^2+2\cdot b^2+c^2+d^2)=(2\cdot a^3+2\cdot b^3+c^3+d^3)$ besides $a=5, b=4, c=6, d=1$ has other non trivial solutions with a,b,c,d positive integers?

Comment: Do you mean different values? If not, take $a=b=c=d=1$.

Comment: As a rough estimate based on the prime number theorem there ought to be about three $k$-digit numbers such that the base-ten concatenation of $2^{n+1}-1$ and $2^n-1$ is prime, for each $k$.

Comment: A suggestion: replace the two $d$'s in the equation you ask about with a $d^2$ on the left and a $d^3$ on the right.

Comment: Why not make this homogeneous on each side since $1=1^2=1^3$? This is equivalent to @BarryCipra's comment.

Comment: @Barry Cipra now i replaced as you suggested

Comment: Another possibility with some appealing symmetry is $$(a-b+c-d+e-f)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2)=(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3+f^3)$$ with nontrivial solution $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(6,1,5,5,4,4)$ (and appropriate permutations thereof).

Comment: Note that your change to $d^3$ significantly changes the problem.  It invalidates many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation $a*(2*a^2+2*b^2+c^2+d)=(2*a^3+2*b^3+c^3+d)$ is equivalent to
$$2ab^2+ac^2+ad=2b^3+c^3+d$$
I find the below solutions assuming all of the variables are in the range $1$ to $9$.  I just did a search.

[image]

Comment: Mllikan besides a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, the only solution with d=1 seems to be a=5,b=4, c=6, d=1?

Comment: That is correct if you want $a,b,c,d$ to be nonzero digits.  If you don't restrict the values to $9$ or below Eric Towers has more cases.

Comment: can you proof that?

Comment: I did a complete search in the space I described.  That is a fine proof (assuming it is done correctly).  There are only $9^4=6561$ cases to check

Answer (score 2):

This section of this Answer is responsive to the version of the Question which asked for positive integral solutions to $a (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 + c^2 + d^2) = (2 a^3 + 2 b^3 + c^3 + d^3)$.

Notice that $c$ and $d$ are interchangeable, so we may impose $c \leq d$.

One way to look at this is $b,c,d \geq 1$ and $a =\frac{2 b^3 + c^3 + d^3}{2 b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$, when that is an integer.  This leads to the question, does that ever happen?  Yes.  Notice if $b = c = d$, this is $a = (4b^3)/(4 b^2) = b$, so $a = b = c = d$ is a solution for any choice of $a$.

\begin{align*}
&(a,b,c,d)  &  \text{giving}  \\
&(4,4,4,4)  &  384  \\
&(5,5,5,5)  &  750  \\
\end{align*}

[Cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) with variable order $c, d, a, b$, gives five cylindrical components.  Exhibiting an integer point in a component or showing that a component has no integer points is not easy.

- $c \geq 1$, $d \geq 1$, $a = b = \frac{c^3 + d^3}{c^2 + d^2}$, when this is an integer.  The fraction is always an integer when $c = d$ and is sometimes an integer otherwise.  Examples: $(1,1,1,1)$, $(9,9,5,10)$
- $d \geq c \geq 1$, $a > \frac{c^3 + d^3}{c^2 + d^2}$, and $b$ is the least real root of $2x^3 -2ax^2 -a(c^2 +d^2) +c^3 + d^3$.  Examples:  $(9,10,5,5)$, $(17,18,2,14)$, and $(251,255,51,251)$.
- $d \geq c \geq 1$, $a$ is the least real root of $8x^3 + 27(c^2+d^2)x - 27(c^3+d^3)$, and $b$ is the middle root of $2 x^3 - 2 a x^2 -a(c^2 +d^2)+c^3+d^3$, when those roots are integers.  Having exhausted my tools for determining whether this components has integral points, I am unable to find any or prove that there are none.  (Taking intersections with CADs having different variable orders splits this component into pieces, for instance $a \geq 2$, $b = 2 a/3$, $c = 2 a/3$, and $d$ is the least real root of $9 x^3 - 9 a x^2 - 4 a^3 = 0$.  It's unclear whether that root is ever an integer for an integer $a$ divisible by $3$.
- $d \geq c \geq 1$, $r$ is the least real root of $8x^3 + 27(c^2+d^2)x - 27(c^3+d^3)$, $r < a < \frac{c^3 + d^3}{c^2 + d^2}$, and $b$ is the middle root of $2 x^3 - 2 a x^2 -a(c^2 +d^2)+c^3+d^3$, when this root is an integer.  Examples: $(4,2,3,5)$ and $(5,2,2,6)$.
- $d \geq c \geq 1$, $r$ is the least real root of $8x^3 + 27(c^2+d^2)x - 27(c^3+d^3)$, $r < a < \frac{c^3 + d^3}{c^2 + d^2}$, and $b$ is the largest root of $2 x^3 - 2 a x^2 -a(c^2 +d^2)+c^3+d^3$, when this root is an integer.  Examples: $(5,4,1,6)$ and $(17,15,5,20)$.

---

The below is responsive to the first version of the Question, which asked for positive integral solutions to $a (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 + c^2 + d) = (2 a^3 + 2 b^3 + c^3 + d)$.

Well, $a = b = c = d = 1$ is pretty obvious, giving $6$ on both sides.

One infinite family is $a=b=c = 1$, $d$ any positive integer, giving $d+5$.  There don't seem to be more with $a = 1$, but I don't know how to prove that.

Here are eight more.
\begin{align*}
&(a,b,c,d) & \text{giving}  \\
&(2, 1, 7, 243) & 604  \\ 
&(2, 1, 100, 979998) & 1980016 \\ 
&(2, 2, 8, 384) & 928  \\ 
&(2, 2, 68, 305184) & 619648  \\
&(2, 3, 19, 6155) & 13084  \\
&(2, 41, 1, 131117) & 268976  \\
&(2, 41, 26, 147342) & 302776  \\
&(2, 41, 27, 149343) & 306884
\end{align*}

Cylindrical algebraic decomposition, using the variable ordering $b,c,a,d$ of your equation gives three solution families:

- $a = b = c = 1$ and $d \geq 1$, e.g.,  $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,1,108)$.
- $b = 1$, $c \geq 2$, $1 < a < \frac{c^3+2}{c^2+2}$, $d = \frac{c^3 - a c^2 - 2a + 2}{a-1}$, when $d$ is an integer, e.g., $(2,1,3,7)$ and $(109,1,126,2497)$.
- $b \geq 2$, $c \geq 1$, $1 < a < \frac{c^3+2b^3}{c^2+2b^2}$, $d = \frac{c^4 - a c^2 + 2 b^3-2ab^2}{a-1}$, when $d$ is an integer, e.g., $(5,2,6,3)$ and $(3,3,100,485\,000)$.

(The variable ordering $a,b,c,d$ gives more families, some of which appear to be empty, and most of which require bounds on $b$ and $c$ that are somewhat complicated algebraic functions of the prior variables.  The previous version(s) of this answer used that ordering, but the new ordering is used to aid readability.)

Comment: what if $a\neq b\neq c\neq d$?

Comment: they should be infinite

Comment: no no ok thank you!

Comment: @EnzoCreti : Even stronger: $|\{a,b,c,d\}| = 4$.  $(4,2,3,5)$.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious solution lies where a,b,c,d all equal 1 as:
$$1\cdot(2\cdot1^2+2\cdot1^2+1^2+1) = (2\cdot1^3+2\cdot1^3+1^3+1)$$

Comment: this seems a trivial solution